# Embedded Browser failed to load in Android Studio inside Flutter inspector

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, android-studio-3.0

"I am unable to get embedded browser inside flutter inspector. It's Showing "The embedded browser failed to load". I am not getting any issues while running `flutter doctor -v`.Can anyone suggest how to resolve it?.My Android Studio version is "Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2021.3.1 Patch 2"[image]

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled it.Now I am not getting the error